Wireguard handshake, but no ping
I'm stuck at the most basic step, which is configuring PC2 (10.0.0.3) in order to allow connections from PC1 (10.0.0.1). Just a simple connection, no VPN or anything like that, for now.
I am using Fedora Workstation, and I can't seem to find the rule to make it work. Disabling firewalld works, as well as setting the target to ACCEPT. Both machines are configured to use port 51820/udp, so I'm not really sure what else I should do.
So far I have this:
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --add-interface=wg0 --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --add-port=51820/udp --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
PC1

[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/32
PrivateKey = hidden
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = hidden
Endpoint = hidden:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32

PC2

[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.3/32
PrivateKey = hidden
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = hidden
Endpoint = hidden:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32

This is the tcpdump output on PC2 when I ping from PC1. Somehow the pings are being received, but no response or connectivity on PC1.
sudo tcpdump -nn -i wlp3s0 udp and port 51820
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on wlp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:56:47.997045 IP PC1_PUBLIC_IP.51820 > 192.168.1.23.51820: UDP, length 128
22:56:49.022044 IP PC1_PUBLIC_IP.51820 > 192.168.1.23.51820: UDP, length 128
22:56:50.114223 IP PC1_PUBLIC_IP.51820 > 192.168.1.23.51820: UDP, length 128
22:56:51.070079 IP PC1_PUBLIC_IP.51820 > 192.168.1.23.51820: UDP, length 128
22:56:52.346737 IP PC1_PUBLIC_IP.51820 > 192.168.1.23.51820: UDP, length 128

sudo tcpdump -nn -i wg0
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:58:09.918580 IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1000, length 64
22:58:10.943419 IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1001, length 64
22:58:11.967695 IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1002, length 64
22:58:12.990758 IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1003, length 64
22:58:14.014762 IP 10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.3: ICMP echo request, id 48, seq 1004, length 64

PC1:
ping -c 10 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.0.0.3 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9217ms

